# Return sum of a range based on cell value text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For example:

| Platform | Genre | Title | Owned? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Games | Sports | Game 1 | Y |
| Games | Sports | Game 2 | N |
| Games | Action | Game 1 | N |
| Games | Action | Game 2 | N |
| Movies | Thriller | Movie 1 | Y |
| Movies | Thriller | Movie 2 | N |

I want to be able to have a count of how many titles I own per Genre. So, I know there are 2 sports games available, but I only own Game 1 - Which formula do I need to sum this data?

I am able to retrieve the number of titles by looking up a combo of both the Platform and Genre, but I am struggling to use the same combo lookup to retrieve the amount I own.

Hope this makes sense to someone.

Tried vlookups, concatenation, IFs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `GROUPBY()` it will simple and easy to read however one need to use `MS365` with `Beta` Channel enabled:

[image]

---

```
=GROUPBY(B2:B7,D2:D7,COUNTA,,0,,D2:D7="Y")
```

---

Or, Using `LET()` with `HSTACK()` & `COUNTIFS()`

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Genre, B2:B7,
     _Owned, D2:D7,
     _uGenre, UNIQUE(_Genre),
     HSTACK(_uGenre, COUNTIFS(_Genre,_uGenre, _Owned,"Y")))
```

---

Or, Use `Pivot Tables`

[image]

---

- Place the `Genre` field in rows area,
- Place `Owned` field once in values area and in columns area, filter the columns with `Y` and ensure to summarize the values by count. This will give you the one you are expecting.

---